# Convert na_character_ to "NA"

Tags: r

I would like to convert `NA_charcater_` to `"NA"`.

Data:

```
iris_test <- head(iris)
iris_test[c(1,4),c(2,3)] <- NA_real_
iris_test[c(1,2),5] <- NA_character_
iris_test$Species <- as.character(iris_test$Species)
iris_test$NAs <- NA_character_
iris_test

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  NAs
1          5.1          NA           NA         0.2    <NA> <NA>
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    <NA> <NA>
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa <NA>
4          4.6          NA           NA         0.2  setosa <NA>
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa <NA>
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa <NA>
```

Expected_output:

```
expected <- iris_test
expected[c(1,2),5] <- "NA"
expected$NAs <- "NA"
expected

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species NAs
1          5.1          NA           NA         0.2      NA  NA
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2      NA  NA
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  NA
4          4.6          NA           NA         0.2  setosa  NA
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  NA
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  NA
```

I tried the following but it failed miserably:

```
iris_test[(sapply(iris_test, class)=="character")&is.na(iris_test)] <- "NA"
```

Comment: It is not recommended to create `"NA"` because there are multiple versions of `NA` already i.e. `NA_character_` and `NA_real_` which gets automatically assigned based on the type.  Your code needs to be `i1 <- sapply(iris_test, is.character);
> iris_test[i1][is.na(iris_test[i1])] <- "NA";`

Comment: for what purpose? printing the data frame, writing to csv?

Comment: For display, ```NA_character_``` does not display properly in csv

Comment: you can use `write.csv(data, file = 'data.csv', na = 'missing')` to change how na appears in a csv without changing the data

Comment: @peter861222 What do you mean "NA_character_" does not display properly in csv? How are you reading/writing the file? R will only write out "NA" when saving to a text file like CSV. It does not store the strongly typed version (other programs that read CSV files would not understand that). What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I generally use `write.csv(..., na="")`, this puts nothing (no space, no `NA`, nothing) in the fields in the CSV file. It's much easier to do that than to reassign `NA` to `"NA"`, whether from `NA_character_` or `NA_real_` or `NA_complex_` or any of the others.

Comment: In the downstream, ```NA_character_``` is displayed as blank, which is not desirable. Therefore, I prefer to show "NA" instead of blank

Comment: As others have pointed out, this is clearly an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info/). I strongly suggest the OP reviews their primary objectives instead of pursuing this dire "NA" procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to convert to `"NA"`.  The issue in the code is that `class` returns a vector of length different than the `matrix` output of `is.na`.  An option is to subset the columns based on the `class` and then apply the `is.na` on the subset and do the assign

```
i1 <- sapply(iris_test, is.character)
iris_test[i1][is.na(iris_test[i1])] <- "NA"
```

-output

```
> str(iris_test)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4
 $ Sepal.Width : num  NA 3 3.2 NA 3.6 3.9
 $ Petal.Length: num  NA 1.4 1.3 NA 1.4 1.7
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4
 $ Species     : chr  "NA" "NA" "setosa" "setosa" ...
 $ NAs         : chr  "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me why my attempt fails

Answer (score 2):

We could use `replace_na` wrapped along with `as.character()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris_test %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(as.character(.), "NA")))
```

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species NAs
1          5.1          NA           NA         0.2      NA  NA
2          4.9           3          1.4         0.2      NA  NA
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  NA
4          4.6          NA           NA         0.2  setosa  NA
5            5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  NA
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up with the following solution:

```
iris_test%>%mutate_if(is_character,replace_na,"NA")
```